# Is it possible to implement singleton design pattern without lock, but using volatile?

Tags: c#, singleton, volatile

Can we use the volatile keyword, because as I understand it provides instance freshness

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static volatile Singleton instance = null;
    private static readonly object padlock = new object();

    Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                instance = new Singleton();
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "provides instance freshness"?

Comment: Nope, you can still end up creating two instances of the `Singleton`. Thread one sees `instance == null` and so is about to enter the body of the `if` - but then it gets pre-empted and Thread two also sees `instance == null` and also enters the body of the `if`, creating a new `Singleton`. Then thread one resumes and ALSO creates the `Singleton`. Worse - thread two might have returned and some other code now has a reference to the `Singleton` that is subsequently replaced by a different one.

Comment: volatile is for the complete opposite of a singleton. Singleton means 'changes never' and volatile means can change at any time.

Comment: [Implementing the Singleton Pattern in C# by Jon Skeet](https://csharpindepth.com/articles/singleton)